# pass down getServerSideProps data of nextJs to nested childs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

in next js ssr page after getting data from api, how can i pass it to nested components without using props, is there something like useConext but in server side?
(the reason i dont want to use props is that not passing not necessary data to a parent component)

```
Home(data)
--ParentComep1
  -- tab1(data.part1)
  -- tab2(data.part2)
  index.js
```

Comment: There's no mechanism to do it directly from `getServerSideProps`. If you don't want to use props then use React context in your components.

Answer (score 0):

it seems i was wrong and context works in server side for this purpose